# how to remove an object from embedded array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Here is the schema of my collection "profile"

```
{ 
        _id : ObjectId("123"), 
        name : "Tommy", 
        defaultrates : 
        [ 
                {_id : ObjectId("111"), rate : 35.0, raisedOn : "5/2/2009"}, 
                {_id : ObjectId("222"), rate : 55.0, raisedOn : "5/3/2010"}, 
                {_id : ObjectId("333"), rate : 65.0, raisedOn : "5/5/2010"} 
        ] 
}
```

I want to remove the first index of default rates ({_id : 111, rate : 35.0, raisedOn : "5/2/2009"}).

The result should be:

```
{ 
        _id : ObjectId("123"), 
        name : "Tommy", 
        defaultrates : 
        [ 
                {_id : ObjectId("222"), rate : 55.0, raisedOn : "5/3/2010"}, 
                {_id : ObjectId("333"), rate : 65.0, raisedOn : "5/5/2010"} 
        ] 
}
```

I did this in the console:

```
db.profile.update({'_id: ObjectId("123")},{ $pull: { 'defaultrates':{'_id': "111"}}},{ multi: false })
```

But sadly, it didn't gave me the desired output.

Please help. What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: ...update({'id: .... you forgot to close the quote?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But still, it didn't gave the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing and matching quotes and double quotes indiscriminately. Try this:

```
db.profile.update({
"_id": ObjectId("123")
},
{
    "$pull": {
        "defaultrates": {
            "_id": ObjectId("111")
        }
    }
},
false,
true
);
```

that false is multi. And true is upsert (if not available, insert one).

Comment: Just didt it. The result was: "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0

Comment: It did not modify the collection. I wonder what I am missing?

Comment: ok try this one. I edited my answer. I forgot to add object ID inside default rates

Comment: Still didn't gave the desired output. Do you have any other ways in order to get the desired output?

Comment: what is the output you are seeing?

Comment: I just have some typographical errors, but your latest solution works very fine. Thanks a lot.